# Problem with coc-clangd

Tags: neovim, filetype-c++, plugin-coc, filetype-c

I use coc and coc-clangd for C/C++. When I want to use gtk I get this message:
[image]

When I compile the file with command below, the process completes successfully.

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Why I get this error?

More info:

OS: Debian

Editor: NeoVim

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: You need to tell `clangd` how your project is built and where to find (non-standard) libraries, source files and headers etc., by generating `compile_commands.json` or similar.

When using language servers, `clangd` in this case, it needs to be told how the project is built. This includes, but is not limited to, compiler flags, linked libraries (and versions), header files in non-default locations, compiler, compiler version etc. Language servers for newer languages often just work™, but being C, the level of magic is low and you're expected to provide this info/configuration.

A widely adopted and supported way is to generate a `compile_commands.json` file. Tools such as [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html#prop_tgt:EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS) support generating this file automatically for you, but it can also be generated manually (although I'd advice against it since it doesn't scale very well).

Comment: 1- Library that I used is in the standard libraries' path. Problem is this:
I should use `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` when I compile and clangd does not use it when compiling so sends this message. How can I resolve this?
2- Can you send a sample `compile_commands.json`?
3- I updated question's picture